# How to play video from web worker [fix invisible tab - playing video]

Tags: javascript, html5-video, web-worker

How to play video from a web worker?

The only info that I found was
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSourceHandle

It is experimental [no problem] but the example is not fully clear to me I need more data about passing src and playing the video at the end.

The objective is to make playing video in the background [inactivity / losing browser tab focus]

I am also interested in hackertimer solution if somebody has experience...

Any suggestion?